# Aerospike: How to handle max number of sets 1023 limitation per namespace

Tags: aerospike

I am using Aerospike 3.4. community edition. It is known that aerospike supports only 1023 sets per namespace. In my situation, I may cross that limit. One way I could handle it may be include the set name with the PK and have everything in one set. In this case how do I iterate through the records in particular set. There may be other challenges in this approach. Can anyone help with this 1023 sets limitation?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This looks like a data modeling issue rather. Could you explain your usecase and data modeling that you are using?

Comment: Using the single set method you mentioned, you could also store the set name into another bin and create a secondary index on that bin. This will use more RAM but iterating over a "set" would be faster than an actual set.

Comment: @Anshu, 
Currently, each set will be having thousands to lakh of records with email id as PK with 'n' number of bins like created date, updated date, rating, balance, location etc.,  The number of bins varies record to record.  Each set is associated to a client.  There can be thousands of such clients.  Please help.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a right solution to my usecase? - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could use one set 'users' with the PK as client_id:email, and use a secondary index to optimize the requests to a specific client.
This way you won't be restricted to sets limitation, and still have great performance on complex iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I have exactly done. Migrated the data from old data model to new data model. One query I need to clarify is, I have also couple of supporting sets like activities, subscriptions, winners etc., Even these set are per client, hence I end up with thousands of clients.  
I have migrated everything to one single set along with the 'users'. Is this fine?  
OR I could have had different sets for activities, subscriptions and winners.

Please suggest.  Thanks.

Comment: This is what I have exactly done. The PK as users:client_id:email for users, winners:client_id:email for winners, subscriptions:client_id:email for subscriptions.  All are in single set.  Is this fine?  
OR I could have had different sets for activities, subscriptions and winners. Please suggest.

Comment: Sets could be compared to tables in relational databases, it would make more sense to store data on different sets. Using keys to difference your data may work, but if you store it in different sets not only will you be able to organize it better, but also configure secondary indexes specific to each set. Regarding the thousands of clients issue, it shouldn't be a problem. Aerospike will handle it fine, I manage a couple clusters with dozens of millions of keys with no problem. It all depends on the way you configure the cluster and instances, and how your application interacts with it.